# Can't access array's elements in child component in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, components, two-way-binding

Problem is:

I have an array called wycieczki in **parent.component.ts** where I can easily (for example) do something like `console.log(this.wycieczki[0])`;
but when I pass it to **child.component.ts**, trying to do the same will result in `undefined`
Additionally, `console.log(wycieczki)` works in **child.component.ts**

Binding code (in case I am missing something, but I did check it with regular variable and it worked):

**parent.component.html**
`<app-child [(wycieczki)]="wycieczki" ></app-child>`

**child.component.ts**
`

```
  @Input() wycieczki: Wycieczka[] = [];
  @Output() wycieczkiChange = new EventEmitter<Wycieczka[]>();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.wycieczki)
    console.log(this.wycieczki[0])
  }
```

`

Original idea was to have the child component filter the wycieczki array, and then problems appeared.
Will probably look in comments when I get up tomorrow. Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

`<app-child [(wycieczki)]="wycieczki" ></app-child>`
to
`<app-child [wycieczki]="wycieczki" ></app-child>`
It should work.
`()` is used for two-way data binding i.e @output of child.

Comment: I see no changes to the console output with this solution

Comment: Can you share payrent.component.ts?